# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' on Spark-Submit

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit, bootrun

Created a spark structured streaming application using spring boot.
The bootRun works fine, but when deploying the same jar using "spark-submit", gives me the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Following is my dependencies list from build.gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.1')
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.3.1')
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')
compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.6.1'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0"
compile group: 'org.eclipse', name: 'yasson', version: '1.0.1'
compile (group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1.2')
```

Help Required! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Spark has earlier version of 'javax.validation:validation-api', without "getClockProviderClassName" method.

Options like "userClassPathFirst" can help:
[Classpath resolution between spark uber jar and spark-submit --jars when similar classes exist in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150656/classpath-resolution-between-spark-uber-jar-and-spark-submit-jars-when-similar)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it didn't work. Tried with the following configs
   " SparkConf()
                .setAppName(appName)
                .setMaster(masterUri)
                .set("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst","true")
                .set("spark.executor.userClassPathFirst", "true"); "

Still getting the same error even when deploying in cluster mode

Comment: Option have to be used in spark-submit parameters. Setting in SparkConf is too late - application already started with incorrect libraries.

Comment: Still the same error! Following is the spark-submit command -> [[ spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true mySparkJob-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ]]