java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(Ljava/time/Duration)
Getting error while consuming records from kafka.
I am using spark-submit to launch my job like below:

sparksubmit 
--class com.aexp.gnics.orchestra.batch.KafkaLoader.KafkaLoadDriver 
--master yarn --deploy-mode client 
--queue $hadoop_job_queue_name 
--files ${log4j_file_path},${ssl_truststore_location_config},${ssl_keystore_location_config}

--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=500 
--driver-memory 2G --executor-memory 1G 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode=NEVER_INFER 
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=${spark_metastore_warehouse_dir} 
--conf spark.memory.fraction=0.8 
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${log4j_file_path} " 
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${log4j_file_path}
-DlogFileLoc=${m5_kafka_load_log_file}" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${log4j_file_path}
-DlogFileLoc=${m5_kafka_load_log_file}" \ ${jarPath} ${2} ${rollup_name} ${4} >> ${m5_kafka_load_log_file} 2>&1

I am using below kafka-clients and spark version:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-cp1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.502-mapr-636</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

I am getting error for below code of line:
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMinutes(1));

Error:
[ERROR] 2024-07-31 03:36:33,623 org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2 org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain - org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lorg/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lorg/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords;


The Duration method was added in later versions of the clients. You can just give 1 minute in seconds... But why not use structured streaming to read from kafka?

This has to be a batch job. Structured streaming is not required here. But similar code with Duration is working on another server. Also, I checked poll method documentation. It takes java.time.Duration as argument

SparkSQL can also read in batches. Using read instead of readStream. Regarding Duration, kafka-clients less than version 2.0 don't have this method. Is there another kafka-clients library being loaded on your application classpath? There's another Spark configuration for setting the user classpath first

Yes we can read but with Spark 2.x we cannot explicitly specify group id for kafka consumer. In my usecase there are restrictions to specify group id.

Duration is not supported with kafka-clients 2.x
So I used below and it solved my problem:
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(60000);


It is supported, though. I think your MapR / YARN cluster might have a lower version of the clients in the classpath? Did you try userClasspathFirst executor option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150656/classpath-resolution-between-spark-uber-jar-and-spark-submit-jars-when-similar#31195142
